# Python's json.load weird behavior

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a specific value from log files in a directory.
Now the log files contains JSON data and i want to extract the value for the id field.

JSON Data look something like this

```
{
    id: "123",
    name: "foo"
    description: "bar baz" 
}
```

Code Looks like this

```
def test_load_json_directly(self):
    with open('source_data/testing123.json') as log_file:
        data = json.load(log_file)
        print data

def test_load_json_from_iteration(self, dir_path, file_ext):
    path_name = os.path.join(dir_path, '*.' + file_ext)

    files = glob.glob(path_name)
    for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as log_file:
        data = json.load(log_file)
        print data
```

Now I try to call the function `test_load_json_directly` the JSON string gets loaded correctly. No problem there. This is just to check the correct behavior of the `json.load` function.

The issue is when I try to call the function `test_load_json_from_iteration`, the JSON string is not being recognized and returns an error.

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it definitely opening the same file? Are you sure? Try printing each filename in the loop.

Comment: Yes it is opening the same file. I am also able to confirm that i can see the contents by adding log_file.read()

Comment: Agree to @DanielRoseman, please check all `files` once you get it from `glob.glob`

Comment: @juankysmith i tried your suggestion and encountered an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @juankysmith `json.load` takes an attribute with the `read` attribute. You mean `json.loads` (note the "s"). Moreover this shouldn't make any difference

Comment: @DanielRoseman i've verified that the files are existing and being read accordingly. Still the same

Comment: JSON itself is wrong. Key from JSON should in double quotes ex: `"id"` and so on. And you missed 1 comma after `"foo"`.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani nice catch. I'm correcting it now.

Comment: Woooo woooo ... :)

Comment: @HarshaBiyani still the same. I've verified that the JSON data is correct. Still the same issue.

Comment: @BreakBB json.loads takes in a string, while json.load takes an object. I've tried both still the same issue

Comment: @PunctuationMark : Please paste your JSON here =>  https://jsonlint.com/ and validate.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani i already did that and the JSON data is correct. It's not a data issue.

Comment: What does your `files` list looks like after it is loaded by glob?

Comment: The only issue I can see is that there's a file in your directory with invalid json data. Can you remove all json files and just keep one and test it?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal valid point. Will try it now.

Comment: then only issue in file path. Try by printing `files` list before looping on single file. Check its type. It should be `list`. No any syntax or logical issue is there..

Comment: @PunctuationMark and also, instead of using `json`, try using `simplejson`. Like this: `data = simplejson.load(log_file)`. It will show you more detailed errors like where the json failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your json is invalid. The property names and the values must be wrapped with quotes (except if they are numbers). You're also missing the commas.

The most probable reason for this error is an error in a json file. Since json module doesn't show detailed errors, you can use the `simplejson` module to see what's actually happening.

Change your code to:

```
import simplejson
.
.
.

data = simplejson.load(log_file)
```

And look at the error message. It will show you the line and the column where it fails.

Ex:

```
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 5 column 17 (char 84)
```

Hope it helps :) Feel free to ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: I've added a try catch to handle errors and iterated on more than 1k files. I found out that there is 1 file that does not contain any data. Thanks for the help!